# What does the fork_rv return?

Tags: c++

I know that fork() creates a duplicate process (clone) meaning two identical copies of address spaces are created - one for the parent and one for the child. This process becomes child process of the caller. However, I am confused as to what is inside fork_rv (see comment in code below)

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main()
{
int fork_rv;
printf("Before: my pid is %d\n",getpid());
fork_rv=fork();
if (fork_rv == -1)
perror("fork");
else if (fork_rv == 0)
printf ("I am the child. my pid=%d\n",getpid());
else
printf ("I am the parent. my child is %d\n",fork_rv); /* What is inside fork_rv What gets printed exactly? The address of the child?) */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the Linux manual page for `fork`:

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and
>   0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

Comment: I know that if fork is successful, it returns 0 in child and PID of child is returned in parent and if fork is unsucessful, it returns -1 in the parent. However, what would be returned if it returns anything other than a 0 and -1, say anything greater than 0 in the program above?

Comment: @Anon it's the PID of the child. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: I just don't understand the last line of code. else
printf ("I am the parent. my child is %d\n",fork_rv)

Comment: @Anon it prints the PID of the child.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While @Brian's answer is already correct, maybe explaining the logic behind these return values makes it easier to understand:

- -1 for error should be clear.
- 0 as value for the child process makes sense because the child process can always get its own pid (`getpid()`) as well as the pid of its parent process (`getppid()`).
- All values > 0 are the pid of the new child process that was created, returned to the parent process.
   Since a process can have multiple child processes, a 'get child pid' function is not possible: The pid of which child should it return? And with a 'get children pids' function that would return a list of all child processes pids, it would be cumbersome to find the pid of the latest, new child process.

Comment: Oh my thank you so much! That clear things up for me quite a lot! :) My question should have been What's the logic behind the return values. Now what i just don't get is what does "returning a number" e.g. returning -1 look like "behind the scenes"? Just wondering as I don't see the value -1 being returned after running this code. Going to try and figure that out tomorrow. Ugh, maybe studying computers is not for me